# Change sort order for view when exposed filter text field submitted

Tags: 8, views, search

I have a view that by default is ordered by date. It has several exposed filters one of which is for filtering by text (we use it as a search field). I'd like the view sort to change to Relevance when a user submits a search but I also want to set it so it only does this once in case the user changes the sort order and then modified their search string. Is this possible? I'm using Better Exposed Filters, fwiw.

The view content source is "content datasource" from the drupal search api.

Answer (score 0):

If you order your view by relevance first, then date, when there is no text entered all articles will be given the same relevance score, so this will achieve what you are after.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this doesn't seem to be happening in my view. In fact, without a text string, I'm not sure what its sorting by... certainly not date. I forgot to mention this isn't a normal content view but its using "Content datasource" from the drupal search api. I suspect that's why I'm seeing different results (no pun intended) then what you described.

Comment: I have used this technique successfully with search api previously. You can temporarily add the relevance as a field to the output, that might help with the diagnosis.

Comment: I poked around and figured out that when set to relevance with no text string its sorting by NID. Our authored dates have been manipulated, so they aren't the same order as the NID.

Comment: @fallenturtle this isn't the usual behaviour, I can't say where the sort by nid is coming from.

Comment: I'm revisiting this and have at least realized I was mistaken in thinking it was ordering by NID and in fact its ordering by created date ascending. Seems part of the issue is that there are no secondary sorts when all criteria are exposed. A partial solution seems to be to set relative as the first exposed sort criteria and then at the bottom of the sort criteria lists add the desired initial sort criteria unexposed, in my case date descending. Still I wish I could just have the text search field when submitted switch to sort by relevance unless another sort criteria has been chosen.